# Neo4j.rb How to make one query when filtering parameter may or may not be present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cypher, neo4j.rb

User and Place are the two nodes having has_many realtionship

```
@places = User.find(4).places

@places = @places.where(dog: false) if params[:no_dogs]
```

can I make these two into one so that if param comes then it involve where condition other wise ignore it

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the `find()` method takes zero arguments.  Maybe you're wanting this?

```
@places = User.places # Calling the association gives an unexecuted proxy to a query to build

@places = @places.where(dog: false) if params[:no_dogs]
```

Or if you wanted to work with the `User` model:

```
@users = User.all

@users = @users.where(dog: false) if params[:no_dogs]
```

Comment: then I can assume I need to use conditional where in queue like the way I mentioned and also mentioned